# How to get number value of string value that is changing ; javascript

Tags: javascript, string, object

I'm trying to get latitude and longitude value out of string.
If I set the location on the map, the map api gives me string value like below.

```
var location = {map: geo="20.471884,-157.505,6" p="Hawaii"}
```

and I'd like to get the number values 20.471884, -157.505 and 6 into var lat, lng.

how can I make it in javascript??

Comment: [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) would be a start. Have you done any research or made any attempts? What specifically are you having trouble with. Not to mention, that "object" isn't valid at all.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `-157.5056`?

Comment: @JackBashford Either that or the OP has missed a variable

Comment: thanks for keyword, will search for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, make your object valid. Then just `split` on a comma to extract the desired values.

```js
let obj = {
  map: {
    geo: "20.471884,-157.5056",
    p: "Hawaii"
  }
};

const [lat, lng] = obj.map.geo.split(",");
console.log(lat);
console.log(lng);
```

<sub>The name is `obj` not `location` because `location` is reserved.</sub>